# Stub not getting called in jasmine unit test

Tags: jasmine, jasmine-jquery, jasmine-node

```
 function fun{
    A.B.C().D(someconstant);
    $(element).prop("checked",false).trigger("change");
    }

    describe(()=>{
        let triggerStub: Sinon.SinonStub; 
        let Dstub: Sinon.SinonStub;
        beforeEach(() => {
        triggerStub = sandboxInstance.stub($.fn, "trigger");
        Dstub = sandboxInstance.stub(A.B.C(),"D");
        });
        it("Verification",()=>{
        fun();
        sinon.assert.calledOnce(Dstub);
        sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(triggerStub,"change");
        });
```

Getting an error that Dstub has been called 0 times. Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell without knowing more about your code, but it looks like this line isn't stubbing what you think it's stubbing:

```
Dstub = sandboxInstance.stub(A.B.C(),"D");
```

This seems to be stubbing the `D` function on *one* call of `A.B.C()`, but not the other. In other words, the `A.B.C()` in `fun` is not the same `A.B.C()` as in your `beforeEach`, so you're not stubbing the correct thing.

If you can stub the *prototype* of whatever `A.B.C()` returns, that might solve your problem.

You can also stub the result of `A.B.C()` to return the `Dstub` you want:

```
describe(() => {
  let triggerStub: Sinon.SinonStub; 
  let Dstub: Sinon.SinonStub;

  beforeEach(() => {
    triggerStub = sandboxInstance.stub($.fn, "trigger");

    // Create the stub for D.
    DStub = sandboxInstance.stub();

    // Make A.B.C() return that stub.
    sandboxInstance.stub(A.B, 'C').returns({
      D: Dstub
    });
  });

  // ...
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help!:) Did you mean sandboxInstance.stub(A.B,"C").returns({D:Dstub}); ? Also, the asserts would remain the same,right ?

Comment: @user2597100 Yes, the assertions should remain the same, if I'm understanding things correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the help :) This is working fine. :) Can you clarify another doubt of mine ? If A.B.C().D() is also returning any object, how can I stub A.B.C().D() to make it return the particular object when property C has already been stubbed ?

Comment: @user2597100 Perhaps something like this? https://gist.github.com/EvanHahn/dfbfdbc9f16ead72d377